# Params from @ManagedService path are null

Tags: atmosphere, path-parameter

actually I would to retrieve two params from the @ManagedService path, but i get only null value.
The code is something like:

```
...
import org.atmosphere.config.service.PathParam;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.ManagedService;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.Singleton;

@Singleton
@ManagedService(path = "/chat/{myId}/{destId}")
public class Chat {

  @PathParam("myId")
  private String mittId;

  @PathParam("destId")
  private String destId;

  @Ready
  public void onReady(AtmosphereResource r) {
    logger.info("User {} want to chat with {}", mittId,destId);
  }
```

Debugging "mittId" and "destId" are null.
There's some error on the code or something that I forget?
Actually I'm using Atmosphere-runtime 2.3.0.

Thanks to anybody that will help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client is correct. I resolve removing @Singleton annotation. Now while I'm debugging I can see the value of the two params.

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Either you are not sharing the enough *or the original* back-end code or your client application is calling the chat resource incorrectly.

I tested your example and both path parameters *are* populated. 
Please have a look at the example in the Atmosphere Github page about the the [multichatroom](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/blob/master/samples/chat-multiroom/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/samples/chat/ChatRoom.java), especially the client implementation.